# facebook api with python error process finished with exit code 0 but not showing output

Tags: python, django, api

```
import json
import django_facebook

def main():
    token={"EAAYweZAE8V28BAEvrqNvhcwiC5Y2KahleAQihgEwKacedR82qEEYWZAGvgQc8OdinAyg6jSNEapN3GR4yBgXNQY9ta2bhuVsBclR8YKRKqDF5CdKmgW0NWRDZCKlvVkmE8ZB1NRqaN6uspKkR38ZA5eVLmROxSRZAm7xgPAfZC2jKSPVmGOYZCivg05pAj0w43CpAS4JKam8xwZDZD"}
    graph=facebook.GraphAPI(token)

    fields=['id,name,age_range,hometown']

    profile=graph.get_object('me',fields=fields)

    print(json.dumps(profile,indent=4))

if __name__=="main":
    main()
```

i am creating this program and its executing but not showing output???

Comment: You need to use `if __name__ == '__main__':`, not `'main'` :)

Answer (score 0):

When a python module is executed as the principal entry point, the `__name__` variable will be set to `"__main__"`.

The line `if __name__ == "__main__"` therefore allows us to execute certain code if this module is being run explicitly and represents the main entry point to the program. Code inside that `if` block will not be executed if the module is imported from a different module.

In your case, you are testing `__name__` against the string `"main"`. You need to change this to `"__main__"` and your code will run as expected.